# Center last line of justified text in Safari and Chrome ("text-align-last" not working)

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

Hi I am trying to format my web paragraphs so that the text is justified and the last line is centered. I found the CSS property "text-align-last" which allows me to specify the alignment for the last line.

The problem is that this property is not supported by Chrome and Safari (yet...?).

Anyone have an alternative or a trick to do that?

The W3C manual: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-align-last.asp

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible in CSS alone.

Here's a JavaScript solution, in which a clone lies behind the element.  The element has `text-align: justify` and the clone has `text-align: center`.

The code then reduces the height of the original element so that only the clone's last line displays.

```js
var p= document.getElementById('lorem'),
    clone= document.createElement('p');

clone.textContent= p.textContent;
clone.className= 'clone';
p.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, p);
p.style.height= p.offsetHeight - 14 + 'px';
```

```css
#lorem, .clone {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 14px;
  font: 14px arial;
  width: 500px;
}

#lorem {
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
}

.clone {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular, but this code should work fine with it.  I don't think it's possible in CSS.

Comment: is this a right practice? I can see the clone on my browser, 1px shows. is safe?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "1px shows"?  Do you mean that you see one pixel of the cloned element?

Comment: yes, I can see one 1px of the cloned element, also, the cloned element is good for SEO or it can affect SEO performance, I mean do search engines pick it up as duplicated content? thanks.

Comment: I don't think search engines would pick this up, because it would mean they'd need to run the program instead of simply parse it.  What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome on linux , ubuntu 16.04. I think yours is a very clever workaround. thanks, nevertheless, I decided to align-left finally.

Comment: You could try changing `14` to `15` (or mayber `13`?) in the JavaScript code.  Sorry, don't have Ubuntu to test this.

Comment: to clarify for people unable to understand the significance of "14", it is the line-height of the your element. so you can actually make this dynamic by simply getting the line-height property of that element and assigning it there!