# CSS, Is there way alternatively make "text-align-last" in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

text-align-last works on major up to date browsers, but for some it won't work as expected. e.g. mobile browsers included.

What I am trying to do is to make justified text with last line centered.

this works on major browsers

```
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: distribute;
  -moz-text-align-last: center;
  -webkit-text-align-last: center;
  text-align-last: center;
```

I suppose in angularjs we should use directive, but I am not so good at those. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707908/center-last-line-of-justified-text-in-safari-and-chrome-text-align-last-not-w) shows plain javascript way of doing it. Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit**

I am not sure if this is going to work

```
.directive('justCenter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {          
       scope.$watch(attrs.myCenter, function (value) {
        var clone = element.createElement('p');
        clone.textContent= element.textContent;
        clone.className= 'clone';     
        elemt.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, element);
        element.style.height= p.offsetHeight - 14 + 'px';

       });                      
    }
  }
})
```

Can anyone help me to get it work...?
maybe something like this form

```
<just-center my-center="something"> </just-center>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [doc from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last) says it is an experimental technology. Also see [support for mobile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last#Browser_compatibility)s and be not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example in Angular using the code you specified above.

Plnkr example: https://plnkr.co/edit/2AD8ePWuGJeSbvcQIKQj

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module('angularApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
});

app.directive('justifyLastCenter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var p = element[0];
      var clone = document.createElement('p');
      clone.textContent = p.textContent;
      clone.className = 'clone';
      p.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, p);
      p.style.height = p.offsetHeight - 14 + 'px';
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Justify and center last line of text Angular directive</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <div>
    <p id="lorem" justify-last-center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#lorem, .clone {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 14px;
  font: 14px arial;
  width: 500px;
}

#lorem {
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
}

.clone {
  text-align: center;
}
```