# How can use text-allign-last CSS Property in safari? It Not works in safari

Tags: html, css

text-allign-last is not supported in safari.How can i apply it?This property is applied in major browsers but it not applied in safari.thanks for any solution.

I need to apply allign type justify for div and for last line i need to use center.that what i used text-allign-last property. but it not applied in safari.

Comment: you cant because it is not at all supported in safari....not even with any prefix

Comment: Is there any tricks?

Comment: unfortunately not...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707908/center-last-line-of-justified-text-in-safari-and-chrome-text-align-last-not-w This link has an answer for my question

Comment: obviously with the help of javascript you can do anything but its not possible with pure css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Obviously could not able to fix this issue with the pure CSS. but we can able to fix with the JavaScript help.

After searching for the solution, I have found the solution in the [Center last line of justified text in Safari and Chrome ("text-align-last" not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707908/center-last-line-of-justified-text-in-safari-and-chrome-text-align-last-not-w).

Thanks for helping me to find the answer.